# Programmatically added navigation items not displaying

Tags: swift

I made a function to display navigation items and bar buttons, however for some reason it doesn't seem to work and it doesn't display anything

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
        configureViewComponents()
    }


func configureViewComponents(){
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 0/255, green: 0/255, blue: 201/255, alpha: 1)
        navigationItem.title = "Login"
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "arrowshape.turn.up.left"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleSignOut))
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.tintColor = .white
```

Comment: Does it work if you add `super.viewDidLoad()` right above configureViewComponents()?

Comment: @pietrorea nope it never worked.

Answer (score 1):

What colour is the background of your navigation bar because you are making the left button item have a tint of white. If your navigation bar is also white I do not believe this will be displayed, as the colours are just the same.
Therefore, I suggest trying to change the tint of the button and see if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 0):

If trying to render SFSymbol Icon, use the `UIImage(systemName:)` initializer:

```
navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(systemName: "arrowshape.turn.up.left"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleSignOut))
```

Comment: @Mellopria What's not working, Is the image visible in barbuttonitem ?